# Sitecore Content Hub non-taxonomy facets not visible

Tags: search-facet, content-hub

I've created an entity with relation to other entity (which is not a taxonomy). How can I configure search facets to search by that relation (relative entity's name in that example)?

[image: Relation diagram]

I've tried to add facet with:

- Facet type -  Field
- Definition - Relative
- Property - Name (Relative.Name)

Also I've tried that facet (just to be sure it's not my case):

- Facet type - Taxonomy
- Taxonomy item - Relation (Relative)

Both ways didn't show me any facet for that relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to use facets in your search components is to define a "Taxonomy definition"

> For Facets - you need a Taxonomy definition. Taxonomy definition "allows for it to be searchable as a filter/ facet or in advanced search query options on the different search pages"

After you have defined your Taxonomy item, you can then add a taxonomy relation to your entity definition (your Taxonomy definition is Parent to your Entity definition)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
By the way, to be clear: the only way to search by some related entity is to define that entity as a taxonomy. Am I right?

Comment: yep, that is the way content hub currently works. If this resolves your query, please mark the answer as accepted to help other people with similar queries

Comment: Sure, thanks. Hope it will help somebody